# OpenGL glActiveTexture vs glBindImageTexture

Tags: opengl

I'm new to OpenGL and I'm confused about these to functions.
I thought that glActiveTexture activates a texture "slot" or sth like that,
and the next texuture you bind is bound to this slot.
But now I saw glBindImageTexture (call: `glBindImageTexture(0, texHandle, 0, GL_FALSE, 0, GL_WRITE_ONLY, GL_R32F);`) and I cannot see the difference between this function and glActiveTexture and glTexImage2D.

Actually I dont even know the difference between a texture and an image, so could you explain the differences?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`glActiveTexture` and `glBindImageTexture` have *nothing to do with one another*. Despite the similarities of their naming, they are for two completely different things.

`glActiveTexture` sets the currently active "texture image unit".

`glBindImageTexture` binds an image from a texture to a specific "image unit". Note the key phrases in quotations. "Image units" are used for shader [image load/store operations](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Load_Store). They are *not* used for [shader sampler accesses](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_%28GLSL%29); that's reserved for "*texture* image units." Yes, they're named similarly, but they're not the same thing.

Image load/store is for arbitrary reading and (primarily) *writing* of image data from a shader. In GLSL, these are defined by `uniform` variables with the prefix `image` (`image2D`, for example). Regular texture access is handled by uniform variables prefixed with `sampler` (like `sampler2D`).

Sampler texture access allows you to do things like [filtering](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture_Filtering), automatic mipmap selection, and so forth. Image load/store doesn't. It's just reading memory from a specific image within a specific texture.

To use a texture with samplers, you bind the texture to a texture image unit (typically with `glActiveTexture`/`glBindTexture`). To use an image from a texture with image load/store, you use `glBindImageTexture`. The set of texture image units is in no way related to the set of "image units".

Neither function replaces the other, nor do they have any conflicts. The number of "image units" has no bearing on the number of "texture image units". And the current "texture image unit" has no effect on `glBindImageTexture`. or anything else to do with "image units".

Comment: So while a samplers provides special functions like filtering (linear, nearest, mipmapping), images provide a raw read/write interface to a bound image. right?

Answer (score 4):

Think of texture units (which is what glActiveTexture selects) as a slot for a cartridge. And glBindTexture actually inserts the cartridge into the slot selected with glActiveTexture.

glTexImage2D is what loads "paint" into the actual cartridge. And a multitexturing capable GPUs (all modern GPUs are multitexturing capable) can use from several cartridges (textures) filled with different images (using glTexImage) at the same time, where each cartridge is setting in a texturing unit. One interesting thing is, that the same cartridge can be inserted into multiple units at the same time.

#### Update due to comment

in a very coarse sense you may think of image data flowing this way.

[image: simplified GL texture image data flow]

Comment: ok but what are these "images" or how they differs from regular textures? and how about the functioned glBindImageTexture, as mentioned above?

Comment: @Jim: I added a diagram, that I hope may help.